# setting opacity with css :hover doesn't work for child element

Tags: html, css, opacity

I am trying to make a link appear when the mouse is hovered above a div, but i can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="rendezvous" style="position: relative">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <div class="remover" style="width: 32px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 15px; opacity: 0;">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rendezvous:hover .remover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6uLTr/

The curious thing is that the css selector works, i can test it by setting the border for example. But the same method doesn't work when i set the opacity. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rules in the `style` attribute have higher precedence than rules defined in author stylesheets.  You can either use `opacity: 0.5 !important` (not the best idea) or define the other rules in the stylesheet as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/6uLTr/1/

Comment: +1 but could you please explain why the !important isn't a good idea?

Comment: !important is really a band aid solution for less than ideal code. It's fine to use, but a better option is to address the problem directly by removing inline styles that are causing problems. If you start to litter your site with !importants, it quickly becomes a horrendous mess.

Comment: @EdmundJoseph essentially what ralph.m said, it becomes a mess.  What happens when you need to override an `!important` rule?  And then what happens when you need to override that rule?